# Can I default Bluetooth to off on my laptop Lenovo T61

Tags: laptop, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate Bluetooth on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup)

After every boot Bluetooth is on by default. I only very occasionally use Bluetooth so  I would really like this to be defaulted to off but be able to start it without a reboot or some command line change which I probably wont remember in 4 months time when I need it. 
Any help greatly appreciated