# How to disable bluetooth in Gnome 3?

Tags: 11.04, login, gnome, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I default Bluetooth to off on my laptop Lenovo T61](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2567/can-i-default-bluetooth-to-off-on-my-laptop-lenovo-t61)

I an using Ubuntu Natty 11.04 with Gnome 3 front end. Every time I login I have in my top right corner an indication that my bluetooth is activated. I want to it to be deactivated by default and activate it on demand not the other way around, any ideas?